# svgicons fieldtype - how to output in template?

Tags: templating, error, svg

I've added a field called **icons** of type [svg-icons](https://github.com/fyrebase/svg-icons) and am able to select icons I've added without an issue. I am having trouble outputting them on the front end however. I get twig errors no matter what I try.

Have done `{{ dump(entry.icons) }}` and get the following output where you can see 11 lines from the bottom the path and name of the select svg icon.

How do I output that to the template?

```
D:\path\to\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php:56:
object(Craft\SvgIconsModel)[700]
  protected 'classSuffix' => string 'Model' (length=5)
  protected 'strictAttributes' => boolean true
  private '_classHandle' (Craft\BaseModel) => null
  private '_attributeConfigs' (Craft\BaseModel) => 
    array (size=6)
      'icon' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'sprite' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'type' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'resource' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'width' => 
        array (size=9)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => float -2147483648
          'max' => float 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 11
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'height' => 
        array (size=9)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => float -2147483648
          'max' => float 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'default' => null
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 11
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
  private '_attributes' (Craft\BaseModel) => 
    array (size=3)
      'icon' => string 'general\design.svg' (length=18)
      'width' => float 512
      'height' => float 512
  private '_extraAttributeNames' (Craft\BaseModel) => null
  private '_errors' (CModel) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_validators' (CModel) => null
  private '_scenario' (CModel) => string '' (length=0)
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{ entry.icons.icon }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used the plugin before, but from glancing at their docs, it looks like `entry.icons.icon` is what you're looking for.

Any other properties on their [SvgIconsModel](https://github.com/fyrebase/svg-icons#svgiconsmodel) should work as well.

Comment: Oh, I see how it is, Brad.

Comment: @StephenLewis I can't help it you have issues committing.

Comment: Brad Bell, Chief Officer of Community Knowledge.

Comment: That works, but I still don't see where it says that in the docs. I would've expected the docs to specifically say something like {{ entry.fieldname.icons }}